# How can I separate six digits in perl and have a / between each section?

Tags: perl, join, split

I have grabbed a string from a file that contains a date, but without formatting.  I want to format that date with a / in between the month, day, and year.  It currently returns mmddyy, but I want it to format as mm/dd/yy for use in a spreadsheet.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is what I have so far...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'd1528235.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
my $datestring;
my $date;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ( !$datestring and $line =~  m/=\((\d{6})/ ) {
    $datestring = $1;
 #   print $datestring;
  my $date;  
  my @date = split(/(\d\d)/, $datestring);
  #foreach my $d (@date) 
    $date = join("/",@date);
#    print "@date\n";
    print "$date\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the fact that a non-matching regex pattern will return an empty list in list context. Using `join` on an empty list will return the null string, which is a *false* value

So the statement `$date = join '/',  /=\((\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/` will set `$date` to either the null string or a date like `12/34/56` if a sequence like `=(123456` appears in the current line

It is usually easier to use `$_` to hold the current line, as it is the default parameter for many built-in functions and often makes for clearer more concise code

It's hard to know what to write as an example as you don't say what else you want to do with your file data. I hope this code is clear enough for you to extrapolate to your own solution; it just prints the reformatted date when the first matching line is read

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;
use autodie;
use re '/a';

my $file = 'd1528235.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my $date;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    chomp;
    if ( not $date and $date = join '/', /=\((\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/ ) {
        say $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  I had something similar, but it was putting double slashes.  This I believe will work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is:

```
my $s = '151211';
say join('/', $s =~ /([0-9]{2})/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of capturing $datestring, you can use capture groups to capture month day and year individually:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my ( $month, $day, $year ) = $line =~ /(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    print "$month/$day/$year\n";
}
```